# ResponseContentType.Blob Corrupted data after saving file/blob

Tags: angular, typescript

After setting `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` I am able to save file on disk. When I try to open it I get errors about corrupted data.
How to save downloaded file with http.get properly in Angular 2?

```
this.birEmwHttp.get('/rest' + nodeContent.replace('{nodeId}', nodeId), {
    responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob 
}).map(response => (<Response>response).blob()).subscribe((file) => {
    console.log('responser: ', file);
    saveAs(file, "file.pdf");
});
```